# Scraping specific elements from various websites and saving them in the same vector

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am new to R and trying to scrape job posts from various URLs (entering them from the same job post portal.

I use the job portal URL to scrape company names, job titles, locations, and links to the official job post (typically on the companies own websites).

I am now trying to scrape the text from the job posts, but I cannot manage to scrape the text and save the full text from a website all together. Either (1) I get too much HTML code that I cannot clean, or (2) I manage to save the text I want but where every sentence is saved individually.

Output examples:
(1)
[1] "ty : Herning , state : Midtjylland , zip_code : 7400 , country : Danmark , latitude : 56.133765 , longitude : 9.001462 } window.initMap( #map-18623 ); if ($( #department-data-18623 ).length) { departmentAddress = JSON.parse($( #department-data-18623 ).html()) window.geocodeAddress(departmentAddress, 18623 ) }"

(2)
[507] "It is a good idea that you create a CV so that the company easily and immediately gets a good understanding of you and your profile."
[508] "It is a good idea that you put your CV online so that the company can easily and immediately get a good understanding of you and your profile."

By using rvest::html_text() i managed to scrape all data successfully from the websites, but I also scraped a lot of HTML coding that I wasn't interested in. I have tried cleaning the texts with this code:

```
clean_text \<- function(text) {
cleaned_text \<- text %\>%
str_replace_all(pattern = "\\n", replacement = " ") %\>%
str_replace_all(pattern = "\[\\^\]", replacement = " ") %\>%
str_replace_all(pattern = """, replacement = " ") %\>%
str_replace_all(pattern = "\\s+", replacement = " ") %\>%
str_trim(side = "both") %\>%
substr(start = nchar(text) - 700, stop = nchar(text))

return(cleaned_text)
}
```

However, I still had a lot of HTML coding that I wanted to leave out.

After finding out that I am only interested in the <p> HTML element from the websites I scrape, I specified my initial code with: rvest::html_nodes("p").

Now I only get the text I wanted to scrape, but now all the texts are saved individually. I want them to saved based on the URLs, so that all text from website 1 can be found by searching for all_job_post_texts[[1]] and so on. I didn't encounter this problem before specifying with: rvest::html_nodes("p").

Is there a way for me to do this?

This is my function for extracting text from job posts:

```
#Extracting links to official job posts on company websites
extract_job_post_links <- function(page) {
  job_post_links <- tryCatch(
    {
      page %>%
        rvest::html_nodes("div h4 a") %>%
        rvest::html_attr("href")
    },
    error = function(e) {
      print(paste("Error:", conditionMessage(e)))
      return(NULL)  #Return NULL when an error occurs
    }
  )
  
  if (!is.null(job_post_links)) {
    #Printing the URLs as scraping them
    print(paste("Scraping URLs from:", url))
    for (link in job_post_links) {
      print(paste("  -", link))
    }
    
    #Create a list to store data from each link
    link_texts <- list()
    
    #Loop through each link and extract text
    for (link in job_post_links) {
      #Access each URL and read the HTML content
      link_page <- tryCatch(
        {
          read_html(link)
        },
        error = function(e) {
          print(paste("Error accessing URL:", link, "Error:", conditionMessage(e)))
          return(NULL)  #Return NULL when an error occurs
        }
      )
      
      if (!is.null(link_page)) {
        #Extract text from the linked page
        link_text <- link_page %>%
          rvest::html_nodes("p") %>%
          rvest::html_text()
        
        #Append the text to the list
        link_texts <- append(link_texts, link_text)
      }
    }
    
    #Return the list of link texts
    return(link_texts)
  } else {
    return(NULL)  #Return NULL when an error occurs
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the URL so we can test the code?

Comment: Seems like you're almost there: `job_post_links |> Map(f = extract_job_post_links)` returns a list of `extract_job_post_links` results, named according to job_post_links. (Whether to use the pipe operator `|>` or include job_post_links as the x-argument in `Map (x, f)` is a matter of taste.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

scraper <- function(page_number) {
  cat("Scraping page", page_number, "\n")
  
  str_c("https://www.jobindex.dk/jobsoegning?page=", page_number) %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_elements(".jobsearch-result") %>%
    map(
      ~ tibble(
        title = html_element(.x, "h4") %>%
          html_text2(),
        company = html_element(.x, ".jix-toolbar-top__company a") %>%
          html_text2(),
        area = html_element(.x, ".jix_robotjob--area") %>%
          html_text2(),
        desc = html_element(.x, "p") %>%
          html_text2(),
        published = html_element(.x, ".jix-toolbar__pub") %>%
          html_text2() %>%
          str_remove_all(pattern = "[^0-9]") %>%
          dmy(),
        link = html_element(.x, "h4 a") %>%
          html_attr("href")
      )
    ) %>%
    list_rbind()
}

map_dfr(1:5, scraper)

# A tibble: 100 × 6
   title                                                        company             area                      desc            published  link 
   <chr>                                                        <chr>               <chr>                     <chr>           <date>     <chr>
 1 Praktikant som Process Manager                               JN Data A/S         Silkeborg eller Roskilde  "Vil du være m… 2024-03-04 http…
 2 Kontruktionsingeniør                                         Grædstrup Stål A/S  Brædstrup                 "Dine arbejdso… 2024-03-04 http…
 3 Ingeniørpraktikant til automationsopgaver for elnettet       Energinet           Fredericia                "Læser du elek… 2024-03-04 http…
 4 Praktikant til Server Operation                              JN Data A/S         Silkeborg eller Roskilde  "Er du i gang … 2024-03-04 http…
 5 Projektleder til Middle Office                               Sparekassen Danmark NA                        "Vi søger nye … 2024-03-04 http…
 6 Social- og sundhedsassistent til dagvagt på Benediktehjemmet Fredensborg Kommune Fredensborg               "Vi mangler di… 2024-03-04 http…
 7 Infrastrukturarkitekt – vær med i den grønne omstilling      Energinet           Fredericia eller Ballerup ""              2024-03-04 http…
 8 Social- og sundhedsassistent til dagvagt på Asmundshøj       Fredensborg Kommune Fredensborg               "Asmundshøj er… 2024-03-04 http…
 9 Supply Chain Planner                                         People Executive    NA                        "Har du erfari… 2024-03-04 http…
10 Jobkonsulent til Dagpengeområdet - Jobcenter Esbjerg         Esbjerg Kommune     Esbjerg                   "Jobcenter Esb… 2024-03-04 http…
# ℹ 90 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```